# *FREE* Screencasting Apps & Utilities

Tags: blogs, utilities

I know there has been previous talk on here about screencasting tools/apps, however I thought I would be more specific in what I am after in the hope that it can help me and others :)

I am looking at trialling some screencasts on [my blog](http://cantgrokwontgrok.blogspot.com/). There are numerous reasons for this (hopefully being more helpful to readers, improving my elocution etc.)

So, **do you know of any good FREE screencasting tools & utilities to get started?** I am not interested in apps that cost at this time because I do not want to shell out until I am more comfortable with the medium!

Also, if you have posted screencasts yourself, please feel free to share links **with your answer**, it would be good to see the quality that is produced etc (and drive traffic to your blog/site) ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see this asked often (on other sites) and I have some interest in the topic, so I compiled a little list (just added the last two by looking at the Related sidebar of this question...):

- Free Screen Recorder - http://www.nbxsoft.com/screen-recorder.php (Windows, AVI output)
- CamIt - http://camit.sourceforge.net/ (Windows, OSS, command line, WMV output)
- CamStudio - http://camstudio.org/ (Windows, OSS, AVI/Flash output)
- Wink - http://www.debugmode.com/wink/ (Windows/Linux, Flash output)
- Jing - http://www.jingproject.com/ (Mac/Windows, Flash output)
- Taksi - http://taksi.sourceforge.net/ (Windows, games/3D, OSS, AVI output (any codec))
- Fraps - http://www.fraps.com/ (Windows, real-time video capture, payware (free limited version?), WMV output)

Comment: I own a license to fraps, and I could be wrong but I thought it only works with games (DirectX/OpenGL) for video capture.

Comment: Great list for people to chew on :)

Comment: The Free Screen Recorder is a fake of free software. It is really just a free trial, which expires and costs 25$ to renew.

Comment: @David: thanks for the precision. I explored the site and they says that nowhere, I suppose you discover that when installing the software? :-(

Comment: Exactly! I discovered it after recording something like 30 times. You can see the "Buy Now" button on [here](http://www.nbxsoft.com/member/index/order.php) (no need to login to see it). A "Buy Now" button should not be necessary if all their software were free. Maybe you could mark it as bogus software in your list?

Answer (score 3):

Only works with Windows and Linux (x86), but give [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) a go. It exports to flash directly so should be easy to integrate with your website.

Answer (score 1):

Jing's quite nice, provided you're only recording short clips. And the nice thing is that it can directly upload a recording or screenshot to screencast.com (you get some free space there if you're a jing user)

Answer (score 1):

OK, as a followup, I got a chance to play with some of the tools suggested.

- [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) looked OK, but just didn't cut the mustard. I think the way it "records" is just really inefficient, audio that is layed over the top is also pretty poor due to the gaps the frames produce.
- [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) looks and works pretty damn good! The AVI output is great quality (both audio and video), I don't experience any lag while it is running. **However** - the flash conversion does not seem to work at all for me? I end up with either a white or bitty flash file? (read "useless") **Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

And some more things I have tried (and TBH **I will probably stick with**):

Using [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) to record the screencast in AVI, I had a really good quality output, but it was **huge**. I needed to get things re-encoded with enough quality to be uploaded to the web and actually readable.

So, I started looking for H.264 encoders and came across [this great guide](http://www.dvd-guides.com/content/view/143/59/). This lead me on to the following:

- [x264](http://x264.nl/) - A great H.264 encoder (Command Line).
- [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) - A **awesome** free encoder bit of kit. Does pretty much everything!

And the final result? [My first ever screencast!](http://cantgrokwontgrok.blogspot.com/2008/11/screencast-adding-components-to-aspnet.html) (which I uploaded to [blip.tv](http://blip.tv/)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Capture Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8090/) which is a Firefox add-on.

Comment: Max 5 frames per second, though.