# How to use ImageIO to save multiple BufferedImages to a file

Tags: java, video, javax.imageio

I tried both of the following options:

1.

```
BufferedImage Buffered_Image;
MemoryCacheImageOutputStream MemoryCache_OutputStream = 
     new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Test.mov",false));

while (notFinished)  // Main recording loop.
{
   Buffered_Image=robot.createScreenCapture();         // Capture Screen image.
   try { ImageIO.write(Buffered_Image,"png",MemoryCache_OutputStream); }
   catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

2.

```
BufferedImage Buffered_Image;
ImageWriter writer;
try
{
  ImageOutputStream ios=ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("C:/Test.mov"));
  Iterator writers=ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
  while (writers.hasNext())
  {
    writer=(ImageWriter)writers.next();
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    Out(writer.toString()+"  canInsertImage : "+writer.canInsertImage(0));
    // Got this: com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageWriter@19fcc69  
    // canInsertImage : false
  }
}
catch (Exception e) { }

cntPics=0;
while (notFinished)  // Main recording loop.
{
   Buffered_Image=robot.createScreenCapture();         // Capture Screen image.
   writer.write(null,new IIOImage(Buffered_Image,null,null),null);
   if (writer.canInsertImage(-1)) {
         // Append image at highest index
         writer.writeInsert(-1,new IIOImage(Buffered_Image,null,null),null); 
   } else Out("Writer can’t append image Id : "+cntPics);
   cntPics++;
}
```

Neither of them worked, what's the correct way to save multiple PNG images to a file?

---

**Edit:**

You are right, I found a java program called [Krut](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=129468) that can record screen sessions, but it uses JPEGImageEncoder, the image quality isn't as good as I want, so I wonder if I can use ImageIO to encode the sequence.

If ImageIO can't do it, my next question would be is there a stand alone open source PNGImageEncoder that I can use to encode it? I know there are open source PNGImageEncoders, but they tend to be tangled in projects and hard to get all the supporting files out of it, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create a video (MOV) file by writing multiple PNG files in a row.  This isn't going to work.  You'll probably have to find a third-party library for encoding your images into a video file (which is itself may be a good SO question).

EDIT: I should also note that you may actually be able to get video by writing multiple JPG images in a row to get a form of [MJPEG (Motion JPEG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) but for other formats such as MOV you're going to need an actual encoder.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Re-inventing MNG? Even if you can write multiple PNG images in the same file, it makes a compound file understood by no program (except those you might write).

If, as suggested by Marc, you want to make a movie, you might want to look at QuickTime for Java (QTJava). It is the solution used by [Processing](http://processing.org/) to make movies out of animations/frames. It has several quality/formats, from the worst (but small files) to the highest quality (high file sizes as result).

Comment: Oh, I never heard of it, can it record screen sessions and sound from a PC ? If you are watching a video with sound on PC, can it record that into a movie ? Or if you want to make an instructional video of how to use a PC program with mouse clicks and your voice from a microphone can it record it ?

Comment: Do you really need to code that (eg. to integrate in some software)? If not, you have already lot of tools. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280362 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555